# Send Pytorch's Tensor as message in gRPC

Tags: pytorch, grpc, tensor, grpc-python

I am trying to make a gRPC call to split deep learning between layers in PyTorch. For this, I need to send a Tensor to my cloud for processing using gRPC call. I am currently trying to use the following as message:

```
message Tensor {
    google.protobuf.Any out = 1;
}
```

and in my pyTorch code,

```py
from google.protobuf.any_pb2 import Any
...
request = Any()
...
request.Pack(out)
send_grpc_msg(request)
```

Here, `type(out)` is `<class 'torch.Tensor'>`. However, this code is giving the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg_inference.py", line 95, in <module>
    out = detect_images(Image.open("images/dog.jpg"))
  File "vgg_inference.py", line 88, in detect_images
    request.Pack(out)
  File "/home/rohit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py", line 78, in Pack
    self.type_url = '%s%s' % (type_url_prefix, msg.DESCRIPTOR.full_name)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

I am also unable to find a good resource of using `ANY` in python.

Thanks